# How to change current time with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show current time on my webpage. When I push `F5`, I can get the time, but it's not changing. Help me..

HTML

```
      <div id="time" class="timer">
          show_time
       </div>
```

Javascript

```
var text2 = document.getElementById("time");
var now = new Date();
var hours = now.getHours();
var minutes = now.getMinutes();
var seconds = now.getSeconds();
var dn = "PM";
if (hours<12)
   dn="AM";
if (hours>12)
   hours=hours-12;
if (hours==0)
   hours=12;
if (minutes<=9)
   minutes="0"+minutes;
if (seconds<=9)
   seconds="0"+seconds;
setInterval(setTime, 1000);
function setTime(){
    text2.innerHTML ="현재 시간: <br>"+ hours + ':' + 
    minutes + ':' + seconds+ "<bn>"+dn;
 }

setTime();
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
const el = document.getElementById('nav-time');

function updateClock() {
   var now = new Date();
   var time = now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds(); 
        
   el.innerHTML = time;    
}

setInterval(updateClock, 1);
```

```html
<li><span id="nav-time">Clock
<span class="divider"> | </span>
```

Comment: Wow it works!! I was dealing with this problem so long. Thank you. Can you explain me how 'const' made this work?

Comment: @WonGyeong Thanks for the comment following is the MDN documentation javascript Date go through it you will find everything about  Date  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: It's really a great site. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
function setTime(){
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML ="현재 시간: <br>"+ hours + ':' + 
    minutes + ':' + seconds+ "<bn>"+dn;
 }
```

You have to add something to your current code so that your `setTime` function actually adds its output to the DOM. I used `document.getElementById("time")` to add the time from your function to the page.

Comment: Thank you! Your comment helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the current time inside the function, otherwise it will return value that you got when function was called for the firs time

```
function setTime(){

var text2 = document.getElementById("time");
var now = new Date();
var hours = now.getHours();
var minutes = now.getMinutes();
var seconds = now.getSeconds();
var dn = "PM";
if (hours<12)
 dn="AM";
if (hours>12)
 hours=hours-12;
if (hours==0)
 hours=12;
if (minutes<=9)
 minutes="0"+minutes;
if (seconds<=9)
 seconds="0"+seconds;

  text2.innerHTML ="현재 시간: <br>"+ hours + ':' + 
  minutes + ':' + seconds+ "<bn>"+dn;
}

setTime();

setInterval(setTime, 1000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1gc8ymkd/

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment!